# Clean android project display error in window in eclipse.

Tags: android, eclipse

When first time eclipse **start all error should appear in problem window** ,**delete this error** manually then my android project run successfully .

And clean up project then same error occur.

i am putting one screen short of eclipse window.
[image]

Please help me ....

Comment: every time u start error occurs and manually do wat to remove error?? just delete error or correct something??

Comment: Your question is not clear. It is difficult to make out what's happening in the screen shot you have provided. Please paste the code and logcat results separately instead of a screen shot. If project clean is not solving your problem try updating your `Android-SDK` and also in case you are importing a project from somewhere else see if R.java and BuildConfig.java is being created or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you didn't import `android.r.java`
2. Make sure `R.java` is generated
3. By seeing screen I can say that if your `r.java` does not exist in `gen` folder then it's a problem with your layout. See layout xml files and remove the errors from there.

Comment: R.java file automatically generated .when i delete error from problem window then successfully run my project.

Comment: that means there exist error in ur layout .... otherwise there must be r.java .... check layout first.. and if still not check ur code or post it here .

Comment: okey u do one thing ..take fresh eclipse and make new project with different package name .....put ur code into that project and change package name at respective places...if it's not problem with ur code than it must work with that .....after this u can be sure that it's problem with ur eclipse....or best way u put ur code here...

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors in Android Manifest. That is common cause of not regenerating R.java file.

Comment: In project there is no error .i am running successfully.my problem is when first time eclipse start ,error comes automatically and when clean project .